# Xamarin : condition `array->len == 1' not met SIGABRT error

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have this code which was running fine with Xcode 8 and IOS 10.3.1 till I updated my Xcode to 9 and Visual Studio for Xamarin.

This is the below code which is throwing error and crashing the app during debug:

```
        // Code fetching data from SQLITE [Package name Sqlite-net-pcl]
        // Result -> System.Collections.Generic.List
        var Result = await _database.GetAsync();
        if (Result.Count > 0){
            try
            {
                foreach (var resultObj in Result)
                {

                Debug.WriteLine("Data {0} ", resultObj.name);
                }
             }
```

When I am debugging the code I can see value inside Result and on expression evaluation for resultObj.name I get the  desired result. But once the debugger reaches to Debug.WriteLine / If I try to utilize resultObj.name it crashes with the below stack trace :

```
2017-09-22 15:06:18.549 LoginPage.iOS[415:35914] error: * Assertion at /Users/builder/data/lanes/5024/152b654a/source/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4714, condition `array->len == 1' not met
2017-09-22 15:06:18.550 LoginPage.iOS[415:35914] critical: Stacktrace:

2017-09-22 15:06:18.550 LoginPage.iOS[415:35914] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2017-09-22 15:06:18.551 LoginPage.iOS[415:35914] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0x00007>
2017-09-22 15:06:18.551 LoginPage.iOS[415:35914] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5024/152b654a/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
2017-09-22 15:06:18.551 LoginPage.iOS[415:35914] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5024/152b654a/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
2017-09-22 15:06:18.552 LoginPage.iOS[415:35914] critical:   at LoginPage.iOS.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00001] in /Users/beingsrv/Projects/Prescriber360-App/iOS/Main.cs:19
2017-09-22 15:06:18.552 LoginPage.iOS[415:35914] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0001e] in <6314851f133e4e74a2e96356deaa0c6c#082A8F72-4318-CDE3-E7A4-8B1E160A93AB>:0
2017-09-22 15:06:18.553 LoginPage.iOS[415:35914] critical: 
Native stacktrace:
```

Also I did tried for loop but facing same issue. 
It was working correct till I updated my device as well as Visual Studio for IOS 11.

Any Idea ?

Comment: You may file a bug here:https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: facing same issue, getting edgy every passing day

Comment: Has anyone filled a new Bugzilla issue? I'm also facing this on Android.

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin Bugzilla is down and there are several reports around. No one from xamarin has commented. This is a mess.

Comment: I had similar issue in debug mode on Step Over. If I set debug breakpoint after the failed line - it works just fine

Comment: @Artiom you saved my day, thank you. This problem still exist in VS 2019 for mac.

Comment: The reason for me was that I had a breakpoint on an `await` and stepped